# How to give chrome_bin path in jenkins for karma integration in mac?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, karma-runner

chrome_bin = /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome doesn't work in jenkins-karma integration. I get the following error:

[Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }

After googling found this as an issue in karma for not properly setting chrome binary. So, How to set chrome binary properly?

Is it necessary to give paths for all browsers individually?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're on a mac so just add it to your ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist

Remember that the path should be to the executable itself rather than to the path leading to it.

Answer (score 0):

alias chrome="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"

run above one then check

Comment: Please edit this to use Markdown formatting.  In particular add 4 spaces before your code to turn it into a code block.  Thank you.  Also if you could explain *why* this solves it that would help a lot (teach a man to fish vs give a man a fish).